# Huge speed difference loading Core Data records on iPhone Simulator to iPhone 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios-simulator

I'm developing a data-driven application using Core Data. I display the tables from the SQLite database in a number of `UITableView`s. One of my tables has >15,000 records.

When I load this table it takes <1 second (usually around the .933 mark) to load on screen. However when I deploy to an iPhone 4, the same table takes around 10 seconds to load.

It was at around 12 seconds, but I changed the fields I fetch, the number of records I fetch, and I've even dabbled in multi-threading, but that's all the time I can shave off.

I was thinking of setting the batch size to be fairly low on the fetch; however, my app makes use of indexing in the `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` and `titleForHeaderInSection:` methods, so I don't know how I'd accomplish it properly without giving a knock-on effect to these methods.

If anybody has any advice or tips for loading data into a table view, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Remember that your app running in the simulator is really a *Mac* app running on your high-powered Mac under OS X! Your iDevice is far less powerful or fast, which is always why you want to test on a device. You have clearly found a bona fide performance issue with your app when running on a device... Since you are using core data, you should look at also using an NSFetchedResultsController, which is specifically designed to be used with table-based core data apps and may help mitigate your problem.

Comment: Hey Mark, just for clarification, I am using an NSFetchedResultsController. That's why I'm surprised it's taking so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that your Simulator runs at your computer's CPU's power. I've read somewhere that the Simulator is usually 16x faster than the actual phone, so there will be discrepancies.

Have you considered doing infinite scrolling? Check [TTTableFooterInfiniteScrollView](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Sources/TTTableFooterInfiniteScrollView.m) from the [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) project.